# How to extend template from project templates folder in app in Django?

Tags: django

I've added the `allauth` package to my Django project. I tried extending a template from the project template folder, but it didn't work. It keeps giving me a 'template does not exist' error. Any idea how to solve this?

```
my-project
    app1
        account
            login.html
    app2

templates
    base.html
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app1', 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**my-project/app1/account/login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<!-- ========== MAIN ========== -->
<main id="content" role="main">
...
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the structure you have here but surely DIRS should be `[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`?

Comment: I have created ‘app1’ to override allauth forms, i.e. ‘login.html’. The ‘base.html’ file is a generic file that is required by all my templates. Thats why I put it in the project template folder. My apps only contain app specific templates. App name ‘account’ is already taken by allauth. Thats why I called my app ‘app1’. Does that make sense?

Comment: " The ‘base.html’ file is a generic file that is required by all my templates" , I hope you took the `base.html` template located into the installed `allauth` package and copied into `project/templates/`. right ?

Comment: @iMitwe No, it’s my own base file.

Comment: `myproject/ template/ login.html`, Add template folder directly under myproject and then add your login.html

Comment: @BidhanMajhi why is this ‘better’ than my approach?

Comment: @dunkubok because you are adding `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app1', 'templates')`, which you should be `os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates')`, this means your template directory is directly in the project directory, very much like media files.